# Best way for QTP Test Results

Tags: qtp

I would not like to see all the events "Done" in the test results window. I want to see only
Pass or failed which are reported with statement Reporter.ReportEvent. Could any please help me with idea or code?

Answer (score 0):

The Run Results Viewer has a filter option for this ("View -> Filters" from main menu).  Simply set the filter to only show Pass and Fail steps when you're looking at the results.

Comment: I am looking for generating the XSLT/HTML results with QTP after the test run with code.